# Bridging a remote site through OpenVPN with broadcast traffic

Tags: openvpn

I am trying to set up a VPN connection between two sites.

- The remote site has a camera running that broadcasts video using TCP, and additionally advertises itself on the network using mDNS/Bonjour.
- In the middle there is a Linux server running on a cloud provider, hosting an OpenVPN server
- The remote site's router (ASUS ROG Rapture GT-AX11000) is connected via OpenVPN to the server
- The local site has a laptop that should be able to connect to the camera and receive the broadast.

Here's a diagram of the architecture:

[image]

So far I've used [this script](https://github.com/angristan/openvpn-install/) to set up OpenVPN and the client configurations. But I couldn't see the broadcast (which was expected).

**What do I have to do to make sure I see the broadcast traffic locally on the laptop?**

I've changed my OpenVPN config to use (selected parts):

```
port 1194
proto udp6
dev tap
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 94.140.14.14"
push "dhcp-option DNS 94.140.15.15"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
tls-crypt tls-crypt.key
crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert server_rgpYVq742Cz4eLEj.crt
key server_rgpYVq742Cz4eLEj.key
auth SHA256
cipher AES-128-GCM
ncp-ciphers AES-128-GCM
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
verb 4
client-to-client
log-append /var/log/openvpn.log
```

This works and lets the laptop and router connect, although I can only reach the router, not the camera and its broadcast.

I now also understand that what I need is not a typical server bridge, which assumes that the OpenVPN server sits behind the router to which outside clients connect.

Instead, I need to bridge the traffic from the LAN (with the camera) to the VPN network, using the capabilities of the ASUS router.

Is that possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view, changing the VPN to a TAP-setup is the only solution to your problem. Let me dig into the details a bit:

A routed vpn setup, which you currently have setup, works at network layer 3. You already noticed, that you need to advertise any network, which is supposed to go through the vpn via `iroute`. But broadcasts work differently, and there are many broadcasts which are at network layer 2 - you will not be able to make them work at all through a routed vpn. (And I have not talked about multicast yet...)

This is where an TAP-VPN comes into play: instead of working at the network layer, it works at layer 2: this kind of vpn wraps ethernet frames. This means any broadcast will simply work - at the cost of the higher overhead (the ethernet header on any ip packet). But up until now, you just have connected your locations with ethernet - you still need to setup your IP configuration on top of that. There are many configurations possible:

- on the server side, you can build a bridge between the eth and tap network adapter, and leave the ip configuration to the DHCP server running on that site
- you could create a dedicated network for you vpn, and let your vpn server assign ips

Reading your question, the most suitable setup for you would probably the bridge - that a local client and a VPN client are on the same network.
This part has nothing to do with vpn; openvpn just delivers the ethernet packets, and it is up to your linux running the openvpn, to "stuff" that ethernet frame into the correct network.

That is what the script you mentioned is made for. Concerning the values, you need to think of a suitable network layout, and implement that.

Let me give you an example:
file `/etc/network/interfaces` :

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 192.168.100.10/24
    gateway 192.168.100.1
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp   off
    bridge_fd    0
    bridge_maxwait 0
```

start openvpn, and execute the following:

```
ifconfig tap0 up
brctl addif br0 tap0
```

This is my configuration to setup the network-bridge on boot - allowing the openvpn server to be started later (and being added to the bridge after startup).

If you want to do this setup with the script provided, you need to understand what is happening: The script is trying to create a bridge, and needs to add the "real" ethernet interface to the bridge. In order to do this, it needs to strip any ip configuration from the eth0 interface, create the bridge, add eth0 to it, and give the ip configuration which was previously on eth0 to the bridge interface. Because of the connectivity loss, I have setup the bridge on boot - that way, I can bring up and down openvpn without connectivity loss to the local network.

This way, whenever a vpn client sends a DHCP request, this request will be forwarded (in my example) into the local network, and being answered by the same DHCP server which is being used for your local clients. I would strongly suggest that you read about linux bridging - this knowlegde is essential, if you want to know what you are doing.

**[edit]**
concerning the IP address in my example - the correct value for you depends on the location of your openvpn-server! For my example, the openvpn-server runs on a device behind the router - which is why I specified .1 as gateway. If your openvpn runs on your gateway, you need to modify these values accordingly! depending on your setup, you even could assign the IP of the br0 interface via dhcp ...

when it comes to the `server-bridge` configuration option, lets have a look at what this option is made for. An exempt from [Here](https://linux.die.net/man/8/openvpn) :

> For example, server-bridge 10.8.0.4 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.128 10.8.0.254 expands as follows:
>
> mode server
> tls-server
>
> ifconfig-pool 10.8.0.128 10.8.0.254 255.255.255.0
> push "route-gateway 10.8.0.4"

Note the `ifconfig-pool` directive! This option is just a shortcut for those, who want to keep their config file as short as possible. But if you want you vpn clients to get an IP via DHCP, this directive is wrong in your setup! It would configure the IP configuration of your clients, instead of leaving this to the DHCP server...

**[edit2]**
In reply to the comments, some clarification is needed. What does bridging mean? It means that you create an ethernet connection between the connected adapters, just like a network switch would do. In your setup, you created a link between your two openvpn clients and the eth interface of your server. Where is that interface going ? Following your picture, it goes into the public internet - that is not what you tried to achieve! you need to create a bridge to your camera...

Creating a bridge means that you link the virtual network to the real network. To be able to reach the camera from your laptop at "local site", you need your packets traverse from the vpn network into the real network at the remote site - and this is possible only, if there is a bridge between the vpn and the real network at the remote site.

Comment: This is great advice already, thank you! I understand now that a single bridge with the TAP interface would suffice. The `.10` IP address, is that the address of the VPN server in its own VPN? And in the `server-bridge` directive, should I use `.1` (for the router) or `.10` (for the server) as the first argument? Further, I am stuck with Ubuntu which uses netplan, so I cannot use `/etc/network/interfaces`, so I will check how to apply your example.

Comment: this is an example from ubuntu, too - there is a way to disable netplan (this is just a personal preference - I hate netplan... ) Concerning your other questions, these are important - I will enhance my answer.

Comment: I enhanced my answer ... and no, the .10 address is the real address of the device running the vpn server. In this setup, there is no difference anymore between "real" ips and ips from vpn... So actually, this ip is both ;-)

Comment: Thanks! Well, the location of the server is (as indicated in the image) on the public Internet without a router in front of it. The only other DHCP server in my setup would be the router at the remote site. It may, however, not always be connected. So I will split the pool, have the router assign its IPs from 1–127, and have the OpenVPN server assign IPs from 127–254, for example. So my `server-bridge` is set to `192.168.100.1 255.255.255.0 192.168.100.128 192.168.100.254`. This seems to have worked – at least I can connect with the clients –, now all I need to do is set up the bridge.

Comment: I updated my question once more. I cannot get it to work – would appreciate your insight. In particular, I am a bit confused since now the router has two IPs – the .1 and .129?

Comment: I should add: this is not like your typical office + mobile laptop setup where the VPN server sits behind the office router. That seems to make it more complex unfortunately.

Comment: well, just as I said, I was just giving an example, and in my example, the openvpn server stood "inside" the site which I wanted to be reachable. In your example, the openvpn server neither is inside the "remote site", nor in the local site. Not an ideal position... if the server should stay there, you could consider leaving the tap device at the server running standalone without any ip (and without being added to a bridge), and adding the tap interface of the client at the remote site to a linux bridge interface...

Comment: Hmm. I didn't figure that I would have to change your example, after all, you kindly included the IP addresses I was using. So I thought this should work in my case. So you mean I don't have to do any bridging stuff on the server. And by "client at the remote site", do you mean the router? So the router somehow needs to bridge its internal network to the VPN? Isn't it doing that anyway? I was able to reach the camera before, when using a TUN setup, by pushing an extra route.

Comment: I edited my answer again - hope this makes it clear now. You need to understand the difference between bridging and routing...

Comment: I do understand that difference. I guess I was further confused by the first examples given. But before switching to TAP, I was able to reach the camera very easily via the router. The router had a TUN connection to the VPN server, and I simply had to add the route for the internal subnet to the VPN setting. So the router already bridges its VPN connection with its local network, no? (It's an ASUS ROG Rapture GT-AX11000 btw.)

Comment: no! you were able to reach the camera because the router is able to ROUTE packets! but a broadcast started from either side will not be able to pass the router, because there is no ethernet bridge.

Comment: Got it. Now the obvious question is: can I do that with this particular router, or am I out of luck?

Comment: I do not know this router - but I am not aware of any router which is able to do network bridging. The obvious answer is: buy / get yourself a cheap network device (any raspi will do), plug it into the remote site's network, and install the openvpn server with bridge on that device...